# What are all the different third-party accessories that I can get for an RCX?

Tags: rcx, 3rd-party, accessories

What are all the different third-party accessories that I can get for an RCX?

Comment: Accessories as in, sensors, motors, gear, books, official, unofficial etc?

Comment: Oh, sorry @Ambo100 I've edited the question to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

About 8 to 10 years ago there was more RCX-compatible sensors makers on the web.  Today, I don't think we'll find them unless we dig into the [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/web/web.php).

It looks like [Techno-Stuff](http://www.techno-stuff.com) is still making some RCX-compatible components.  Also, [Mindsensors](http://www.mindsensors.com) was making RCX-compatible components also but I couldn't find links to them through their website main page (It might be discontinued).  You can probably still buy some through eBay.  Here are two of their RCX compatible products:

- [UltraSonic Proximity Detector v2](http://www.mindsensors.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=29)
- [Motor powered Sharp GP2D12 infrared distance sensor interface](http://www.mindsensors.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=8)

Answer (score -2):

My favorite third party accessory is the Playstation 2 controller interface for the NXT.

http://www.trossenrobotics.com/store/p/5709-Sony-PlayStation-2-Controller-interface-for-NXT.aspx

Also you can check out their entire listing here:

http://www.trossenrobotics.com/store/Search.aspx?searchTerms=nxt&submit=true&type=AND

They have some really great third party accessories that are not that expensive.

Comment: Sadly this question was about the RCX brick, the previous generation from the NXT :(